# How to encrypt emails sent from google form submissions?

Tags: email, encryption, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

So I have a google form that sends it's responses to a spreadsheet, then I have a script that emails the responses to me automatically, but what I want to do is encrypt the emails being sent, is it possible?

Here is the current script:-

```js
function sendFormByEmail(e)
{

    var email = "myemail@domain.com" ;

    var subject = "New Sample Request Submitted";

    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var message = "New Sample Request from Website";

    for(var i in headers)
    message += headers[i] + ' = '+ e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() + "\n\n";

    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
}
```

Comment: you may want to format your code to make it a little more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some funny stuff out there on the internet..., I liked [this one](http://users.dickinson.edu/~braught/courses/cs131s99/labs/lab10.html) for its simplicity (simple substitution ciphers) so I borrowed it and modified it a bit. I also had to write the decoding part but that was easy ;-)

It gives interesting results.

[image]

Above is the result... interested in the code or in the decoded value ? then read below :

*(since you will be receiving the emails you will have the key... I guess it will be rather easy to implement in any email sending code. Reading the decoded messages will be more tricky, I imagine the simplest way would be to create a gmail filter to assign a label to these messages and from there write an app to read them using the decode function.)*

```
function test(){
  var key = "#@&é,?(§è!çà)-_°$*^¨`£ù%=+MPLOKIJUHYGTFRDESZQANBVCXW";
  Logger.log(encode(key,'My name is bond, James Bond'));
  Logger.log(decode(key,encode(key,'My name is bond James Bond')));
}


function encode(key, message)
// Given  : key is a string of the 52 letters in arbitrary order (2 x 26 characters),
//          message is the string to be encoded using the key
// Returns: the coded version of message using the substitution key 
{
  var alphabet, coded, i, ch, index;

  alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

  coded = "";                                      
  for (i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {      // for as many letters as there are
    ch = message.charAt(i);                   // access the letter in the message
    index = alphabet.indexOf(ch);             // find its position in alphabet
    if (index == -1) {                        // if it's not a letter,
      coded = coded + ch;                     // then leave it as is & add
    }                                         // otherwise,
    else {                                    // find the corresponding
      coded = coded + key.charAt(index);      // letter in the key & add
    }
  }
  return coded;
}

function decode(key, message){
  var alphabet, decoded, i, ch, index; 
  alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; 
  decoded = "";                                      
  for (i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {         // for as many letters as there are
    ch = message.charAt(i);                      // access the letter in the message
    index = key.indexOf(ch);                     // find its position in key
    if (index == -1) {                           // if it's not in the key,
      decoded = decoded + ch;                    // then leave it as is & add
    }                                            // otherwise,
    else {                                       // find the corresponding
      decoded = decoded + alphabet.charAt(index);// letter in the alphabet & add
    }
  }
  return decoded;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way of using Apps Script to send encrypted emails. An alternative would be to place the message information in a separate Doc/Sheet, and email a link to it -- that way only those with permission to see the Doc/Sheet will be able to access the information.